# How to create procedural square transparent simulated shadow?

Tags: materials, shaders, shadows, procedural, shadowcatcher

I am new to Blender, and I would like to create a procedural material that simulates a transparent shadow for a cube.

I already know how to create a simulated transparent shadow for a sphere (see screenshot).

I looked for a way to do the same thing but for a cube, but unfortunately I couldn't.

Can someone more experienced than me help me find this solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this? It's made by combining two (different direction) wave textures (scaled so they're each only "one" wave"). You can control the shadow's size and falloff using the ColorRamps:

[image: Shadow]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christopher-bennett